# There are three columns of text on my page but the right column is at the bottom, separated from the other three

Tags: html, css, text, multiple-columns

All three of the text elements are in a div. i want one large one and two smaller ones on the sides of it. The left is fine, so is the middle, but the right column is at the bottom of the page. Both the left and right columns have almost identical css. I want the right column to be like the left. Thanks in advance.

```css
html
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-image: url("woodBack.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#Dove
{
    width: 30%;
    height: 58%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navButtons
{
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}

#buttonDiv
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#mainHr
{
    width: 85%
}

#leftColumn
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border-color: black;
}

#middleColumn
{
    text-align: left;
    border: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#rightColumn
{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border-color: black;
}

#bodyText
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeStyles.css">
    <title>CCEV - Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<img id="Dove" src="headerImg.png">
</div>

<div id="buttonDiv">

<button class="navButtons" >Upcoming</button> <button class="navButtons" >Get Help</button> <button class="navButtons" >Youth Group</button>
<button class="navButtons" >Join Us</button> <button class="navButtons" >Services</button> <button class="navButtons" >Donate</button>
<button class="navButtons" >Contact</button>

</div>

<hr id="mainHr">

<div id="bodyText">

<p id="leftColumn">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
</p>

<p id="middleColumn">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br>
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br>
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br>
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br>
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br>
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br>
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
</p>

<p id="rightColumn">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to achieve your design it's better use flexbox than float...

Comment: ive ever used flexbox before, i will try that if i dont find a soution.

Comment: remeber float remove your content from the normal flow, so this is the good moment to learn flexbox

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little example of how you can achieve this with flex.

I have a wrapper around the columns that has `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` to put the remaining space of the columns in between them

with `flex: 0 0 50%` and `flex: 0 0 20%;` I set the witdh of those columns

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column-middle {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.column-small {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column column-small">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus impedit sunt fugit repudiandae omnis, asperiores voluptatibus inventore sit dolore officia, recusandae hic ratione eum aperiam aliquid. At adipisci, veritatis placeat!
  </div>
  <div class="column column-middle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae consectetur delectus repellendus minima repellat, est rerum, quo numquam animi. Officiis tempore quibusdam fugiat voluptatibus, nesciunt provident dolorem amet deserunt ipsam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae consectetur delectus repellendus minima repellat, est rerum, quo numquam animi. Officiis tempore quibusdam fugiat voluptatibus, nesciunt provident dolorem amet deserunt ipsam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae consectetur delectus repellendus minima repellat, est rerum, quo numquam animi. Officiis tempore quibusdam fugiat voluptatibus, nesciunt provident dolorem amet deserunt ipsam?
  </div>
  <div class="column column-small">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus impedit sunt fugit repudiandae omnis, asperiores voluptatibus inventore sit dolore officia, recusandae hic ratione eum aperiam aliquid. At adipisci, veritatis placeat!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will learn flex as sfili suggested

Comment: I've learned most of flex on this site in case you need it 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/